# Hive: how is it decided which value goes into which bucket?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In hive if I have a bucketed table with CLUSTERED BY (employee_id) INTO 10 BUCKETS, by looking at the values how will I know which value goes into which bucket ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing the data you can not judge which value will go into which bucket. Bucketing works on Hashcodes. For every value, a hash code will be generated and the values with the same hash code will go into the same bucket.

But you can try generating the hashcode for a certain set of values using the hashcode function in java and you can guess this value might go into this bucket.

You can refer to [this link](https://acadgild.com/blog/bucketing-in-hive/) for more details on Bucketing in Hive.

Comment: Thanks @Kiran. I was wondering if i have, say 4 buckets, and 100 unique employee_ids, then as per your answer, values with same hashcode goes in same bucket, how can  2 different employee_ids have same hashcodes. Even though considering if it might generate same hashcodes, how does the range for each bucket is specified, like 0-25 hashcodes goes to bucket A, 26-50 goead to B ..and so on. ?

Comment: Hash codes can be same for different values. If you specify 4 buckets then it will generate 4 kinds of hash codes only for all the values. So all the values with the same hashcode will go into the same bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Buckets works on hashing. It is like creating place holders for your data.If you know that your data has values of varying degrees than it may result in many number of buckets created in order to limit the number of buckets you can always apply some custom logic.Say for example you need to fix the number of buckets to 4 then you can mod (emplyoee_id %4) it will always give you values between 0,1,2,3 and thus Hive will route the data accordingly.